# SceneKit finger panning becomes inaccurate as it moves away from center

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, uipangesturerecognizer

In my `ARSCNView`, I'm drawing a `SCNPlane` with a grid inside. It is a child of `sceneView.pointOfView`. When you drag your finger across it, you can connect the dots in the grid. This works almost perfectly, except something subtly strange is happening: The edge of the tragged line SHOULD track accurately with the finger, but it actually falls ahead or behind depending on how far above or below the center it is respectively.

```
@objc func handlePan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        print("panned")
        let location = gesture.location(in: sceneView)

        let projectedOriginUI = sceneView.projectPoint(SCNVector3(0, 0, gridCon.grid.position.z))
        let placeOnUI = sceneView.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(location.x, location.y, CGFloat(projectedOriginUI.z)))
        let rootNode: SCNNode = sceneView.scene.rootNode
        let positionOnGrid = rootNode.convertPosition(placeOnUI, to: gridCon.grid)

        let state = gesture.state
        let hitVertex = gridCon.hitVertex(location: location, sceneView: sceneView)

        if (state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began) {

            print("began")
            if (hitVertex != nil) {
                let edge = EdgeController.createEdge()
                edge.position.x = hitVertex?.position.x ?? 0
                edge.position.y = hitVertex?.position.y ?? 0

                gridCon.grid.addChildNode(edge)

                draggedLine = edge
                startVertex = hitVertex

                print("Edge added!")
            }
        }
        if (state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended) {
            draggedLine = nil
            startVertex = nil
        }

        if (draggedLine != nil && startVertex !== nil) {

            print("line height changed")
            let _draggedLine = draggedLine!

            let geo: SCNPlane = _draggedLine.geometry as! SCNPlane
            let between = startVertex!.position.y - positionOnGrid.y

            geo.height = CGFloat(between)
            _draggedLine.position.y = startVertex!.position.y - (between/2)
        }

    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why is my finger tracking slightly off here?

Comment: Is the value of gridCon.grid.position.z equal to 0?  ie: projectPoint(SCNVector3(0, 0, 0))